# It would be grateful vs. other expressions

Tags: expressions, email

Looking for some feedback on the stock answer I usually give to Korean learners of English when they use the phrase "It would be grateful if..."

Quick background: I'm an English language instructor/coach for Korean business professionals in Seoul, South Korea. Recently, I have frequently encountered the expression above in students' emails.

My stock answer is that this expression is incorrect because "it" (the situation/event/action) is not a person, so it cannot feel grateful about another person's actions. Students usually then ask, "Well, what about: 'It would be appreciated if...'"

This expression is ok because it is passive construction; 'appreciate' is a verb, not an adjective like 'grateful'.

This seems to me to be the best explanation I have come up with so far. Does anyone have any input/additional comments in the way of a better explanation? Also, along the same lines, how would you then explain the expression:
"It would be embarrassing if..."
Thanks!

Comment: If an obvious (non-participial) or -ing form adjective is used (It would be awkward / good / wonderful / dangerous / handy / ... // boring / exciting ... if you did X), there is (always, as far as I can see) the paraphrase  'Doing X would be/prove awkward / good ...  // exciting...). But the unacceptability of 'Doing X would be grateful' clearly underlines what you say in your third paragraph.  With -ed forms, adding 'by John' to  'It would be appreciated / welcomed /  valued ...' underlines the verbal nature. **However**, idiomaticity ...

Comment: is unpredictable. 'John would like it if you ...' is fine, but 'It would be liked by John if you ...' sounds unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on with expressions such as

> - It would be appreciated if...
> - It would be embarrassing if...

Firstly, they show the desire to depersonalize the request or statement. It would have been equally possible to write:

> - I would appreciate (it) if...
> - I / you would be embarrassed if...

But in some contexts the writer might feel that such a formulation is too direct.

The second aspect to consider here is the sentence structure. *It would be appreciated if...* and *It would be embarrassing if...* start with the [dummy pronoun](https://www.thoughtco.com/dummy-it-in-grammar-1690414) *it*. This is a very common structure in English, in part because it enables the principle of [end-weight](https://www.thoughtco.com/end-weight-grammar-1690594). This is a fairly nebulous concept, but basically it means that longer phrases are typically placed later in sentences than shorter phrases.

You could write:

> A response to my third attempt to settle this issue once and for all would be appreciated.

But this places the shorter phrase at the end, which contravenes the *end-weight* principle. If we use the dummy pronoun, we can create a sentence, which I suspect most people would find more natural:

> It would be appreciated if you could respond to my third attempt to settle this issue once and for all.

Your stock answer to *It would be grateful if...* is fine. But the expression works if they replace *grateful* with *gratifying*.